# Make Gridview column invisible, but still access its data

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, invisible

I have read many posts on this, especially here on this site, but I still can't find exactly what I'm looking for. I'm filling my Gridview in the .cs file, rather than adding to the Columns section of it in the .aspx. I have two fields I want to be able to still reference, but want them invisible. I know  Gridview isn't particularly good for this sort of thing...but is there some way that I can achieve this that I'm missing?

.cs

```
protected void searchFill()
{
    orderByString = orderByList.SelectedItem.Value;
    fieldString = searchTextBox.Text;
    string sqlStatement = "SELECT fName AS [First], lName as [Last], addr AS [Address], email AS [Email], phone AS [Phone], ccType AS [Credit Card Type], length AS [Length], IdentityColumn, processed FROM SecureOrders WHERE fName LIKE '%" + fieldString + "%' OR lName LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR addr LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR addr2 LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR city LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR state LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR zip LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR zip LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR country LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR email LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR phone LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR ccType LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR ccNum LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR ccExp LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR cwaSource LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR cwaJoined LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR length LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR delivery LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR price LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR url LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' ORDER BY " + orderByString;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ToString()))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStatement, connection);
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fieldString", fieldString);
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderByString", orderByString);
        SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "SecureOrders");

        DataView source = new DataView(dataSet.Tables[0]);
        DefaultGrid.DataSource = source;
        DefaultGrid.DataBind();

        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

.aspx

```
 <asp:GridView ID="DefaultGrid" 
        runat = "server" 
        DataKeyNames = "IdentityColumn"
        onselectedindexchanged = "DefaultGrid_SelectedIndexChanged"
        autogenerateselectbutton = "true"
        enableviewstate = "false"
        selectedindex="1">
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Azure"
        forecolor="Black"
        font-bold="true" />
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Processed">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox 
                ID="CheckBoxProcess" 
                AutoPostBack="true" 
                Checked='<%#Eval("processed") %>'
                OnCheckedChanged="CheckBoxProcess_CheckedChanged"
                runat="server"
                Enabled="true" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: What do want to do with these invisible columns on your page?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to do this? Why cant you put them in the .aspx?

Comment: One of them is the IdentityColumn, when you click that row it uses the number in that data to find the corresponding field in the database. The other one, is a little backwards, but I am using that data to fill a checkbox in another column in the database. I would just use that field itself, but it shows up greyed out...

Comment: I guess there isn't a particular reason other than the fact that I don't entirely know how to do it in the .aspx - would there be an easier way to accomplish this if I did add it in the .aspx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you want to use the column value just use `<%# Eval("ColumnName") %>` inside the GridView.
All the datasource (dataset in your case) values are available in the DataBinder within the context of the GridView.

Comment: But the column needs to be invisible.

Comment: Basically, I don't know how to set the column to be invisible.

Comment: The column can be invisible, use the eval way you like, set the style to display:hidden.

Comment: If you can write the code to show what you want done with the field in not hidden state then mention what you want hidden it would help.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use HiddenFields for the values you want to hide. There is no need to create a whole column when you can just have the control hidden.

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdf_Identity" Value='<%# Eval("IdentityField") %>' />
```

When you want to find them just search for them in the gridview row. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) is some msdn documentation that may help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a css class "HiddenCol" with display:hidden. Then style whichever column you want to hide with that class.